# Looking for a way to manipulate .Net CIL at runtime

Tags: c#, java, .net, asp.net, c#-4.0

In Java we have used the javaagent argument and ASM (http://asm.ow2.org/) utilities to modify the byte code at run/load time in memory by the classloader .  (aka Add a method call to a method in a class dynamically).

Once example of this is where you remove all calls to Log4j to speed up an application (http://surguy.net/articles/removing-log-messages.xml).

I’m trying to figure out how to do this same process on runtime with C# / .Net.  I have seen that you can manipulate the CIL for .Net, but I haven’t found an example of this at runtime.

System.Reflection.Emit seems to be the closest .Net equitant where you can dynamically create classes, but is there a way to add to or override existing classes using this?

Answer (score 2):

I have never used [Mono.Cecil](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil) for generating dynamic code (it does make your life much easy if you want to instrument assemblies though).

In .Net if you want to generate code you can use [System.CodeDom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.aspx) and [System.Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.reflection.emit.aspx). One particular useful class that enables you to inject methods dynamically is [DynamicMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the newer features in .net 4, I think most of what your looking for is in the [System.Dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.aspx) namespace.

Check out this post on [DuckTyping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985161/duck-type-testing-with-c-4-for-dynamic-objects)

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I looked at it (I'm pretty much a Java bunny) but I think the Mono project had something called Cecil which did at least some of this.