# Is there a 'generic' way to directly test an object's data?

Tags: c#-4.0, dynamic

It is really cool that I can do the following in C#

```
if (Divide(4, 0) != false)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Cool");
}
...
public dynamic Divide(int x, int y)
{
    if (y == 0) return false;
    return x / y;
}
```

The above code for instance allows me to test easily for Division by Zero exception instead of using try/catch. However, if the code actually returns a valid result, an error is encountered since a bool cannot be compared to an integer - which means, in the comparison, the result is forced to become a static type?

Is there any way to check if the condition is satisfied as well as get the result without causing an error?

Thanks.

Comment: this is interesting, but dynamic isn't really meant to be used this way.  its more of a way to avoid casting dissimilar things that happen to share a similar interface.  this is generally called duck typing.

Comment: I can't see why this is a good idea or good practice.

Comment: @nathangonzalez: Duck typing? I just saw [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2985215/1261657) but I can't understand it, I think it may have what I'm looking for right?

Comment: Honestly, I don't find that "cool" at all; it leads to an untyped mess ..

Comment: @user2246674: I started C# from PHP, so it ignites some form of passion :)

Comment: @rtuner I would use `int?` here, perhaps - and snarkily add that C# still lacks unified syntax for a proper Option/Maybe type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use a `double?` (nullable `double` as its return type? If its null, its not valid.

Another convention I would use is `TryDivide`. Return a `bool` and use an `out double` parameter.

`TryDivide` would look like this.

```
public bool TryDivide(int x, int y, out double result)
{
    result = 0;
    if (y == 0) return false;
    result = x / y;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: hopefully the reason is that his example is really simplistic.

Comment: TryDivide would be the name of the method, signature like `bool TryDivide(int x, int y, out double result)`

Comment: Okay, just tested. So does it mean there's no other way to do this?

Comment: @rtuner it depends. theres many ways to solve a problem. you aren't using dynamic for what its intended.

Comment: I thought that's either called innovation or abuse? Do you think it's the latter?

Comment: @rtuner yea its just extra overhead that can be avoided.

Comment: So, in all cases, this would be extra overhead?

Comment: @rtuner there is a overhead on the runtime to use dynamic