# Custom Class Converting in c#

Tags: c#, class, generics, typeconverter

I stuck converting class..

I have an arraylist that contains 4 different class which are not releated each other.

for example when user choose one like mylist[i], i should convert it, it's certain class and after can use  .. i mean like

```
var type = mylist[i].GetType();
```

so now I have item's type. and when I create a variable as this type i mean like

```
var newItem = (type)mylist[i]
```

but type is not a class so then i cant convert it.

I am not sure if i am clear..

Comment: This is why you should *never* use `ArrayList`. `List<T>` was introduced in .NET 2.0 for a reason; why aren't you using it? By the way; that cast is impossible.

Comment: What Bradley said. If each of the different classes are different types but have the same functionality consider implementing an interface and create an arraylist of the interface type u created

Comment: 4 classes are different than each other. But some properties are same. So, List<T> is useable in this case?

Comment: U can extend them from the same abstract class if they share same properties

Comment: The problem is, these come from webservice, then i can change it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't cat to type defined at run time.

Assuming types you have are similar, but not related you can

- use `dynamic` to switch to late binding. It will allow you to call methods you want at cost of compile type safety. "Duck typing" sample can be found in [Duck type testing with C# 4 for dynamic objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985161/duck-type-testing-with-c-sharp-4-for-dynamic-objects)
- dynamically create methods that will do what you want with types defined at runtime via reflection or expression.

Answer (score 3):

You can't cast to a variable - you have to explicitly state the type. You'll need to check for each class separately:

```
if(mylist[i] is FirstType)
{
    //do something
}
else if (mylist[i] is SecondType)
{
    //do something
}
//etc
```

A possibly better alternative would be to create 4 separate lists using `List<T>` and hold each type separately:

```
var firstList = new List<FirstType>();
var secondList = new List<SecondType>();
//etc
```

Or, if possible, create a base class if the data is similar enough and use a `List<T>`.

```
public class MyBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class FirstType : MyBase
{
}

public class SecondType : MyBase
{
}

var list = new List<MyBase>();
list.Add(new FirstType());
list.Add(new SecondType());
```

As mentioned in the comments, you can use partial classes to do this as well. They allow you to define a class in 2 or more files. For example, see how the `Profile` class you posted is defined as `public partial class Profile : ProfileBase`? You can create your own file and define it again, with other interface implementations. For instance:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public partial class Profile : IMyInterface
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

This is a good overview on partial classes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx

Comment: i know to do that, but i need a variable in that type.

Comment: @Dave u can cast with `Type t = field as Type` and check if t is not null then the cast succeeded?

Comment: The classes come from webservice, so I cant change it.

Comment: Then I would use 4 different lists if possible. They're inherently different things - there's no need to store them together.

Comment: I am developing an ios project in C#. When the user select the row from table, an event triggers, and it gives me an index that selected row's, so if i have 4 list, how i can know which index belongs to ? If I collect all items in one generic list, and i can use this index like mylist[i] , with that i can reach the item.

Comment: But now problem, i should use it as a new variable as wrote on question

Comment: @unbalanced U can change them by using `partial` classes

Comment: I dont understand what you mean? For example, this is from reference.cs (actually service created)     public partial class DynamicViewSearch {
so its already partial class

Comment: and this another class that i am using-----     public partial class Profile : ProfileBase {

Comment: @unbalanced I updated my answer with specifics about partial classes.